# Adding datatables to symfony 3 - data not showing

Tags: symfony, datatable

I tried installing datatables to my Symfony 3 project. I'm new to this and not sure where I went wrong but the data from my MySQL database are not showing.

I have `{{ datatable_render(datatable) }}` on my index page but all it shows in a button to add another entry.

This is my controller

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Shrubs;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Shrub controller.
 *
 * @Route("shrubs")
 */
class ShrubsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all shrub entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="shrubs_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $datatable = $this->get('app.datatable.shrubs');
        $datatable->buildDatatable();
       // $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

   // $datatable = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Shrubs')->findAll();

    return $this->render('shrubs/index.html.twig', array(
        'datatable' => $datatable,


       // 'shrubs' => $shrubs,

    ));
}
/**
 * @Route("/results", name="shrubs_results")
 */
public function indexResultsAction()
{
    $datatable = $this->get('app.datatable.shrubs');
    $datatable->buildDatatable();

    $query = $this->get('shrubs_datatable')->getQueryFrom($datatable);

    return $query->getResponse();
}
```

ShrubDatatable

```
 <?php

namespace AppBundle\Datatables;

use Sg\DatatablesBundle\Datatable\View\AbstractDatatableView;
use Sg\DatatablesBundle\Datatable\View\Style;

/**
 * Class ShrubsDatatable
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Datatables
 */
class ShrubsDatatable extends AbstractDatatableView
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildDatatable(array $options = array())
    {
        $this->topActions->set(array(
            'start_html' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-3">',
            'end_html' => '<hr></div></div>',
            'actions' => array(
                array(
                    'route' => $this->router->generate('shrubs_new'),
                    'label' => $this->translator->trans('datatables.actions.new'),
                    'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus',
                    'attributes' => array(
                        'rel' => 'tooltip',
                        'title' => $this->translator->trans('datatables.actions.new'),
                        'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                        'role' => 'button'
                    ),
                )
            )
        ));

        $this->features->set(array(
            'auto_width' => true,
            'defer_render' => false,
            'info' => true,
            'jquery_ui' => false,
            'length_change' => true,
            'ordering' => true,
            'paging' => true,
            'processing' => true,
            'scroll_x' => false,
            'scroll_y' => '',
            'searching' => true,
            'state_save' => false,
            'delay' => 0,
            'extensions' => array(),
            'highlight' => false,
            'highlight_color' => 'red'
        ));

        $this->ajax->set(array(
            'url' => $this->router->generate('shrubs_index'),
            'type' => 'GET',
            'pipeline' => 0
        ));

        $this->options->set(array(
            'display_start' => 0,
            'defer_loading' => -1,
            'dom' => 'lfrtip',
            'length_menu' => array(10, 25, 50, 100),
            'order_classes' => true,
            'order' => array(array(0, 'asc')),
            'order_multi' => true,
            'page_length' => 10,
            'paging_type' => Style::FULL_NUMBERS_PAGINATION,
            'renderer' => '',
            'scroll_collapse' => false,
            'search_delay' => 0,
            'state_duration' => 7200,
            'stripe_classes' => array(),
            'class' => Style::BOOTSTRAP_3_STYLE,
            'individual_filtering' => false,
            'individual_filtering_position' => 'head',
            'use_integration_options' => true,
            'force_dom' => false,
            'row_id' => 'id'
        ));

        $this->columnBuilder
            ->add('botanicalname', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Botanicalname',
            ))
            ->add('commonname', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Commonname',
            ))
            ->add('borderlinehardy', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Borderlinehardy',
            ))
            ->add('phpreference', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Phpreference',
            ))
            ->add('wetsoil', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Wetsoil',
            ))
            ->add('moistsoil', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Moistsoil',
            ))
            ->add('peatysoil', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Peatysoil',
            ))
            ->add('welldrainedsoil', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Welldrainedsoil',
            ))
            ->add('drought', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Drought',
            ))
            ->add('claysoil', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Claysoil',
            ))
            ->add('sandysoil', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Sandysoil',
            ))
            ->add('loamsoil', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Loamsoil',
            ))
            ->add('infertilesoil', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Infertilesoil',
            ))
            ->add('richsoil', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Richsoil',
            ))
            ->add('compactedsoil', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Compactedsoil',
            ))
            ->add('cityconditions', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Cityconditions',
            ))
            ->add('pollution', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Pollution',
            ))
            ->add('salt', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Salt',
            ))
            ->add('windy', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Windy',
            ))
            ->add('shade', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Shade',
            ))
            ->add('partshade', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Partshade',
            ))
            ->add('fullsun', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Fullsun',
            ))
            ->add('pestproblem', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Pestproblem',
            ))
            ->add('id', 'column', array(
                'title' => 'Id',
            ))
            ->add(null, 'action', array(
                'title' => $this->translator->trans('datatables.actions.title'),
                'actions' => array(
                    array(
                        'route' => 'shrubs_show',
                        'route_parameters' => array(
                            'id' => 'id'
                        ),
                        'label' => $this->translator->trans('datatables.actions.show'),
                        'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open',
                        'attributes' => array(
                            'rel' => 'tooltip',
                            'title' => $this->translator->trans('datatables.actions.show'),
                            'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs',
                            'role' => 'button'
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'route' => 'shrubs_edit',
                        'route_parameters' => array(
                            'id' => 'id'
                        ),
                        'label' => $this->translator->trans('datatables.actions.edit'),
                        'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit',
                        'attributes' => array(
                            'rel' => 'tooltip',
                            'title' => $this->translator->trans('datatables.actions.edit'),
                            'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs',
                            'role' => 'button'
                        ),
                    )
                )
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getEntity()
    {
        return 'AppBundle\Entity\Shrubs';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'shrubs_datatable';
    }
}
```

Entity\Shrubs

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * Shrubs
 */
class Shrubs
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $botanicalname;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $commonname;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $borderlinehardy;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $phpreference;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $wetsoil;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $moistsoil;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $peatysoil;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $welldrainedsoil;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $drought;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $claysoil;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $sandysoil;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $loamsoil;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $infertilesoil;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $richsoil;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $compactedsoil;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $cityconditions;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $pollution;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $windy;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $shade;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $partshade;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $fullsun;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $pestproblem;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * Set botanicalname
     *
     * @param string $botanicalname
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setBotanicalname($botanicalname)
    {
        $this->botanicalname = $botanicalname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get botanicalname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBotanicalname()
    {
        return $this->botanicalname;
    }

    /**
     * Set commonname
     *
     * @param string $commonname
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setCommonname($commonname)
    {
        $this->commonname = $commonname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get commonname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCommonname()
    {
        return $this->commonname;
    }

    /**
     * Set borderlinehardy
     *
     * @param string $borderlinehardy
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setBorderlinehardy($borderlinehardy)
    {
        $this->borderlinehardy = $borderlinehardy;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get borderlinehardy
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBorderlinehardy()
    {
        return $this->borderlinehardy;
    }

    /**
     * Set phpreference
     *
     * @param string $phpreference
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setPhpreference($phpreference)
    {
        $this->phpreference = $phpreference;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get phpreference
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPhpreference()
    {
        return $this->phpreference;
    }

    /**
     * Set wetsoil
     *
     * @param string $wetsoil
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setWetsoil($wetsoil)
    {
        $this->wetsoil = $wetsoil;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get wetsoil
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getWetsoil()
    {
        return $this->wetsoil;
    }

    /**
     * Set moistsoil
     *
     * @param string $moistsoil
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setMoistsoil($moistsoil)
    {
        $this->moistsoil = $moistsoil;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get moistsoil
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMoistsoil()
    {
        return $this->moistsoil;
    }

    /**
     * Set peatysoil
     *
     * @param string $peatysoil
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setPeatysoil($peatysoil)
    {
        $this->peatysoil = $peatysoil;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get peatysoil
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPeatysoil()
    {
        return $this->peatysoil;
    }

    /**
     * Set welldrainedsoil
     *
     * @param string $welldrainedsoil
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setWelldrainedsoil($welldrainedsoil)
    {
        $this->welldrainedsoil = $welldrainedsoil;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get welldrainedsoil
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getWelldrainedsoil()
    {
        return $this->welldrainedsoil;
    }

    /**
     * Set drought
     *
     * @param string $drought
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setDrought($drought)
    {
        $this->drought = $drought;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get drought
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDrought()
    {
        return $this->drought;
    }

    /**
     * Set claysoil
     *
     * @param string $claysoil
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setClaysoil($claysoil)
    {
        $this->claysoil = $claysoil;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get claysoil
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getClaysoil()
    {
        return $this->claysoil;
    }

    /**
     * Set sandysoil
     *
     * @param string $sandysoil
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setSandysoil($sandysoil)
    {
        $this->sandysoil = $sandysoil;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sandysoil
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSandysoil()
    {
        return $this->sandysoil;
    }

    /**
     * Set loamsoil
     *
     * @param string $loamsoil
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setLoamsoil($loamsoil)
    {
        $this->loamsoil = $loamsoil;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get loamsoil
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLoamsoil()
    {
        return $this->loamsoil;
    }

    /**
     * Set infertilesoil
     *
     * @param string $infertilesoil
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setInfertilesoil($infertilesoil)
    {
        $this->infertilesoil = $infertilesoil;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get infertilesoil
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getInfertilesoil()
    {
        return $this->infertilesoil;
    }

    /**
     * Set richsoil
     *
     * @param string $richsoil
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setRichsoil($richsoil)
    {
        $this->richsoil = $richsoil;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get richsoil
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRichsoil()
    {
        return $this->richsoil;
    }

    /**
     * Set compactedsoil
     *
     * @param string $compactedsoil
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setCompactedsoil($compactedsoil)
    {
        $this->compactedsoil = $compactedsoil;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get compactedsoil
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCompactedsoil()
    {
        return $this->compactedsoil;
    }

    /**
     * Set cityconditions
     *
     * @param string $cityconditions
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setCityconditions($cityconditions)
    {
        $this->cityconditions = $cityconditions;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get cityconditions
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCityconditions()
    {
        return $this->cityconditions;
    }

    /**
     * Set pollution
     *
     * @param string $pollution
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setPollution($pollution)
    {
        $this->pollution = $pollution;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pollution
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPollution()
    {
        return $this->pollution;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get salt
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * Set windy
     *
     * @param string $windy
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setWindy($windy)
    {
        $this->windy = $windy;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get windy
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getWindy()
    {
        return $this->windy;
    }

    /**
     * Set shade
     *
     * @param string $shade
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setShade($shade)
    {
        $this->shade = $shade;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shade
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getShade()
    {
        return $this->shade;
    }

    /**
     * Set partshade
     *
     * @param string $partshade
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setPartshade($partshade)
    {
        $this->partshade = $partshade;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get partshade
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPartshade()
    {
        return $this->partshade;
    }

    /**
     * Set fullsun
     *
     * @param string $fullsun
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setFullsun($fullsun)
    {
        $this->fullsun = $fullsun;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fullsun
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFullsun()
    {
        return $this->fullsun;
    }

    /**
     * Set pestproblem
     *
     * @param string $pestproblem
     *
     * @return Shrubs
     */
    public function setPestproblem($pestproblem)
    {
        $this->pestproblem = $pestproblem;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pestproblem
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPestproblem()
    {
        return $this->pestproblem;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

I went through a tutorial and auto generated the datatables so I'm not sure what other info is needed. Please let me know and I'll add it.

Comment: Normally, this line `$datatable = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Shrubs')->findAll();` will fetch all your data for you. In your template, you can use `{{ dump(datatable) }}` to see what you have in your datatable. This example seems little complex for a newbie, you should follow an easy tutorial first.

Comment: I tried $datatable = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Shrubs')->findAll(); and got the error Type error: Argument 2 passed to Sg\DatatablesBundle\Twig\DatatableTwigExtension::datatableRender() must be an instance of Sg\DatatablesBundle\Datatable\View\AbstractDatatableView, array given, called in C:\my_project_name\var\cache\dev\twig\64\64ebbb790b4bb3176faa29fe2180f4e177ee69b760937e6855ba3330396eed8f.php on line 54

Comment: `{{ datatable_render(datatable) }}` is a custom Twig render function. You can comment it like this `{# datatable_render(datatable) #}` and dump your data as I explain in my first comment. That's why I also say that this example is a little complex if you are not confortable with the framework yet.

Comment: array:718 [▼
  0 => Shrubs {#674 ▶}
  1 => Shrubs {#676 ▶}
  2 => Shrubs {#677 ▶}
  3 => Shrubs {#678 ▶}
  4 => Shrubs {#679 ▶}
  5 => Shrubs {#680 ▶}
  6 => Shrubs {#681 ▶}
  7 => Shrubs {#682 ▶}
  8 => Shrubs {#683 ▶}
  9 => Shrubs {#684 ▶}
  10 => Shrubs {#685 ▶}

etc....is what comes from the dump data table

Comment: Now you can format your data as you want. You can try for example `{% for data in datatable %}{{ data.botanicalname }}<hr>{% endfor %}`. Anyway, you are getting your data correctly, you just have to figure out how the custom render function `{{ datatable_render(datatable) }}` works

Comment: Does it have to do with this:
  public function datatablesRenderHtml(Twig_Environment $twig, DatatableInterface $datatable)
    {
        return $twig->render(
            'SgDatatablesBundle:datatable:datatable_html.html.twig',
            array(
                'sg_datatables_view' => $datatable,
            )
        );
    }

Comment: In your example, you have a service that fetch the data from database and format them. To do that, this service need some parameters, that's why you have `Argument 2 passed to Sg\DatatablesBundle...` error if you don't provide the right params. It'll be too long to explain... So, either you follow exactly your tutorial and it should work, or you can customize the view yourself.

Comment: I did follow it exactly and it doesn't show any data in the table....

Comment: That's strange because you are getting your data correctly so you should check again and contact the tutorial's author.

Comment: Is there anyone else that might have any suggestions I'd really like to figure this out. Thanks. I think it has something to do with the twig extentions but I can't get them to work, keeps saying variable doesnt exist.

Comment: ` 
* Renders the js template.
     *
     * @param Twig_Environment   $twig
     * @param DatatableInterface $datatable
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function datatablesRenderJs(Twig_Environment $twig, DatatableInterface $datatable)
    {
        return $twig->render(
            'SgDatatablesBundle:datatable:datatable_js.html.twig',
            array(
                'sg_datatables_view' => $datatable,
            )
        );
    }`
`{{ datatable_render_html(twig, datatables) }}` is what I'd assume as those are the params but it says twig is not a variable

Comment: Bump again. If I add in the$datatable = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Shrubs')->findAll();
//       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); then the dump shows the array of items, but i get an error when i try to display the table saying i need 2 params. if I take it out, and just have the datatables stuff then the dump shows as null, so how do i get my database stuff into my datatables?

Comment: you are still on this :o. You have the data why not do your own template ? Ok I'll try more time, can you show me the class that define `datatable_render_html` ? Also do you have a link to that tutorial ?

Comment: I figured it out, thank you.